# Assign Topic in chm file

Tags: c#, chm

I have created chm file for project using Sandcastle and have assigned topic in that file but I am unable to get particular topic help on UI when I focus particular textbox or button.How to verify whether I have assigned topic correctly or not.
Content of hhp file.

```
[ALIAS]
Demo1 = html\010709fb-ceda-dfce-990c-b8fc6d3427b2.htm
Search = html\4b81b5e6-47d5-1242-1a52-4e7427da77b7.htm

[MAP]
#define Demo1 1
#define Search 2
```

is it right way or not.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at [ShowHelp function fail notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37659537/showhelp-function-fail-notification) and search for HH API testing by FAR HTML as a help authoring tool. Check if you have connected in a proper way:

You can use the ShowHelp method provided by the Help class from the code of your application. Displaying a help topic by its Context Id you'll need:

```
Help.ShowHelp(this, "C:\foobar.chm", HelpNavigator.TopicId, "10001");
```

"C:\foobar.chm" is the full path to your CHM file and "10001" is the Context Id of the topic to display, as specified in your help project.

Please note you can use a `#include` statement too. Open your .hhp file in a text editor and add the sections ALIAS and MAP to the HTMLHelp project file and add the files to your help project:

```
[ALIAS]
#include alias.h

[MAP]
#include map.h
```

The purpose of the two files is to ease the coordination between developer and help author. The mapping file links an ID to the map number - typically this can be easily created by the developer and passed to the help author. Then the help author creates an alias file linking the IDs to the topic names.

**ALIAS file**

In a text editor enter the ALIAS details like IDH_90000=index.htm. Save the file as 'alias.h' in same folder as your help project file.

```
;----------------------------------------
; alias.h file example for HTMLHelp (CHM)
; www.help-info.de
;
; All IDH's > 10000 for better format
; last edited: 2006-07-09
;----------------------------------------
IDH_90000=index.htm
IDH_10000=Context-sensitive_example\contextID-10000.htm
IDH_10010=Context-sensitive_example\contextID-10010.htm
IDH_20000=Context-sensitive_example\contextID-20000.htm
IDH_20010=Context-sensitive_example\contextID-20010.htm
```

**MAP file**

In a text editor enter the MAP details like #define IDH_90000 90000;frmMain. Save the file as 'map.h' in same folder as your help project file.

```
;--------------------------------------
; map.h file example for HTMLHelp (CHM)
; www.help-info.de
;
; All IDH's > 10000 for better format
; ;comment at end of line
;--------------------------------------
#define IDH_90000 90000;frmMain
#define IDH_10000 10000;frmAddressDataContextID-1
#define IDH_10010 10010;frmAddressDataContextID-2
#define IDH_20000 20000;frmAddressDataContextID-3
#define IDH_20010 20010;frmAddressDataContextID-4
```

For further information see [Creating Context-Sensitive Help for Applications](http://www.help-info.de/en/Help_Info_HTMLHelp/hh_context-id.htm)

Comment: @s6771: Please see added link on top of my answer and the link to check with a tool like [FAR HTML](http://www.help-info.de/de/FAR/far_html.htm).